# time umount <mount point> doesn't work

Tags: linux, shell, sh, embedded-linux, busybox

In BBB based custom board I am running a script which formats the emmc with different filesystem and runs the bonnie++ test. I am trying to time all the operation using the time command. Time command with mount as mentioned below works fine.

```
time mount -t <fstype> <dev> <mountpoint>
```

But when I run time command with umount it fails, I am running the umount command with time as follows,

```
time umount <mountpoint>
```

I tried `&&` between time and umount but it didn't work, how should the time umount command be?

Comment: How is it failing exactly?

Comment: Sorry, its my early conclusions without digging further i jumped to conclusion. There were two problems one is with `mkfs.btrfs` and another problem was i was not checking exit of the `mount` & `mount` command. If previous filesystem of emmc is `ext4` then `mkfs.btrfs` doesn't format the filesystem and `mount -t btrfs <dev> <mnt pt>` fails. And test proceeds and further when it is turn for next filesystem umount fails because nothing is mounted on mount point.

Comment: So this is all sorted out then?

Comment: Yes. `time umount <mountpoint>` works. There is not issue with that.

Comment: If there is still an issue you are asking for help with then you need to edit your title and question to indicate the new question. If not then you should probably close it.

Comment: I think, there is bug with `mkfs.btrfs` i just have to do work around and close this question. How do i close the question ? do i have to raise a flag ?

Comment: You should be able to just close/delete the question I would think.